# Вызов методов класса из свойства

Tags: python, ооп

```
connection = db_connect("db.db")
table = connection["table_name"]

table.insert({
    "name": "Alex"
})
```

Как мне обращаться к экземпляру класса через ключ словаря?

У меня сейчас такая ситуация, что в каждом методе параметром передаётся таблица. Хотелось бы избежать такого написания:

```
def insert(table, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

и прибегнуть к такому:

```
table.insert("insert some_data")
```

где table - имя таблицы.

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет ни одного класса, непонятно о чём речь и кто такой db_connect

Comment: это псевдокод, класс не обладает особыми свойствами, чтобы я его писал, поэтому можете использовать обычный :)

Comment: Всё равно непонятно, какое отношение словарь имеет к классам

Comment: Если вы хотите реализовать в классе возможность получения значения по ключу, то реализуйте метод `__getitem__`

Comment: на примере mongodb: db_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")  # MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
current_db = db_client["pyloungedb"]  # dictionary style
collection = current_db["youtubers"]  # current_db.youtubers

Comment: извиняюсь за вставку кода, но на pastebin  и на другие сервисы нельзя